# 95% Confidence Interval for $\sigma^2$ & Determining the Reliability of the Claim

Tags: statistics

Question :

> A manufacturer of car batteries claims that his batteries will last,
>   on average, 3 years with a variance of 1 year. If 5 of this batteries
>   have lifetimes of 1.9, 2.4, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.2 years, construct a 95%
>   confidence interval for $\sigma^2$ and decide if the manufacturer's claim
>   that $\sigma^2= 1 $ is valid. Assume the population of battery lives to be
>   approximately normally distributed.
>
> **Answer** : $0.293 < \sigma^2 < 6.736$. Since this interval contains the value 1,
>   the claim that $\sigma^2 = 1$ is valid.

---

I tried this : the result seems quite different from the given answer.
[image]

Where did I do wrong?

Moreover, I do not understand well the answer "Since this interval contains the value 1, the claim that $\sigma^2 = 1$ is valid.". Can you explain more?

Comment: Suggestion to use math mode for formatting, and not screenshot of handwritten note.

Answer (score 1):

for $(n-1)s^2$ you just calculate the sum of squared errors (SSE).

$s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot SSE \Rightarrow (n-1) \cdot s^2= SSE$

greetings,

calculus

Comment: You don't have to sign your messages.

Comment: @user3491648 Yes, I know. It was in my early times here on MSE.

Comment: Sorry your post turned up in the Closed Vote queue.

Comment: @user3491648 I see. It seems, that somebody is very active in closing posts.